# Prevent new browser window from opening when running Protractor tests

Tags: webstorm, protractor

I'm using JetBrains Webstorm IDE and set it up to run my Protractor tests from inside, and all the command line output shows nicely in the test runner, but the browser window pops up over everything and I find it extremely distracting. Is there a way to stop it from showing? Or forcing it to stay minimized?

Comment: would you like to avoid opening the browser? I'm not sure if it's possible with protractor, as it emulates running code in browser, interacting with it as a user would

Comment: Yes, that would be optimal. I'd also like to use it for unit testing, but it seems like people use Karma for that? Two separate testing tools doesn't excite me.

Comment: protractor can't be used for unit testing - it was designed for running high-level e2e tests; the recommended runner for unit tests is karma. Previously it was possible to use karma + ngScenario plugin for Angular e2e testing as well, but it's now deprecated (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing). So it seems that using 2 testing tools is unavoidable

Comment: I was afraid of that. I wanted to pretend it wasn't true and I was just doing something wrong. I'm surprised that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Karma - but maybe you can do the same thing in Protractor.

My horrible hack for this is to launch Firefox with `-with-tab` instead of `-no-remote` and set the Firefox tab loading behaviour by using the info at http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-stop-firefox-stealing-window-focus.htm - basically by setting `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` to `true`.

This prevents the window stealing focus when you load a new tab. You end up with a lot of tabs though.